# undefined error in code

Tags: php

I have an issue with my php code, i get undefined index in both this lines:

```
$Page = $_GET["Page"];    
if(!$_GET["Page"])
```

It happens only in the first page.. of course it should happen only then..
Could someone tell me how to solve it?

I found something like this but i'm not being able to remove the notice completely.

```
(!empty($_GET['query_age']) ? $_GET['query_age'] : null);
```

I need to know how to implement it in my code, but i'm unable to..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$page = isset($_GET['Page']) ? $_GET['Page']: '';
```

Then you can work with `$page`. The indefined index is because the index is not set in `$_GET` because you have no GET parameter. Then you should set this value in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Page = null;
if (array_key_exists('Page', $_GET)) {
    $Page = $_GET['Page'];
}
```

is the most explicit and precise thing you can do.  You could also use `isset()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Page = isset($_GET["Page"])?$_GET["Page"]:"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET["Page"])) {
     $Page = $_GET["Page"];
} else {
     $Page = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_GET['Page']` is empty and you get an `Undefined` notice (not error). So, before assigning this to `$Page` you should check if there is some data at all:

```
if(isset($_GET['Page'])) {
    $Page = $_GET['Page'];
} else {
    $Page = ''; // $_GET['Page'] is undefined
}
```